# multiple domains on windows azure virtual machine

Tags: asp.net

I have created windows azure virtual machine and opened port 80 default website that is myapp.cloudapp.net then I have pointed my custom domain www.mycustomdomain.com to myapp.cloudapp.net it is working fine. I have created another website in iis with port 81 I have checked it is working on vm but I would like to add another custom domain to the website on 81 , I don't understand how to do that because ip and dns is same , how to give custom domain to 2nd website?

Answer (score 0):

Domains should be set up in IIS. You will need to define host headers for each website hosted on the server. This also means you don't have to define non-standard ports.

[Configuring host headers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the update, glad to hear you got it working. Please mark this as the answer if you are satisfied.